# Using RegEx to rename XML tags

Tags: xml, regex

I am importing lots of employees from a single XML file. Each employee has a section called `<officeData>` and a section called `<personalData>`.  The children of those two nodes look exactly the same and have the same name `<dataItem>`.

I want to use change the elements within `<personalData>` to `<personalDataItem>` and obviously cannot use a global search/replace because of the children of the `<officeData>` node. If I use a look back / look ahead to check I am within `<personalData>` it will find that tag for the previous or next employee.

Is there anyway I can specify a regex pattern to only rename the multiple children within a specific parent XML node?

Comment: please use an xml parser. regex is not the right tool for this.

Comment: With regex: this situation sounds straight out of [Match (or replace) a pattern except in situations s1, s2, s3 etc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23589174/match-or-replace-a-pattern-except-in-situations-s1-s2-s3-etc/23589204#23589204), have a look. I'll compose a solution in a moment.

Comment: Also, which language do you plan to use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a job for a regular expression, but it would be simple using an XSLT stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <!-- copy everything unchanged ... -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- ... except dataItem inside personalData, which we rename -->
  <xsl:template match="personalData/dataItem">
    <personalDataItem>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </personalDataItem>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: It was kind of an experiment to see if/how regex could handle it. I took your advice and decided to go with the right tool for the job rather than using regex just for the learning exercise. I just needed to know if RegEx actually was the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: @PeterMorris for little one off tasks where you know your data then you could probably get away with regular expressions, but if you're getting XML from somewhere else then I'd always recommend using a parser that knows all the rules of XML and will apply them properly (`<someTag>` == `<someTag >`, `&#10;` == `&#xA;`, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

This situation sounds straight out of [Match (or replace) a pattern except in situations s1, s2, s3 etc](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23589174).

With all the disclaimers about using regex to parse xml, here is a simple way to do it.

Here's our simple regex:

```
<officeData>.*?</officeData>|(dataItem>)
```

The left side of the alternation matches complete `officeData` tags. We will ignore these matches. The right side matches and captures `dataItem>` to Group 1, and we know they are the right `dataItem>` because they were not matched by the expression on the left.

On the [online demo](http://regex101.com/r/sB8rO4), notice how only the correct `dataItem>` are highlighted and captured to Group 1, as shown in the bottom right panel.

In your language, in the replacement function, you just look if Group 1 capture is set. If so, you replace the match to `personalDataItem>`. If not, you replace the match with itself (i.e., no change).

This is a straightforward task, but, depending on your language, you may be able to find code samples to do this Group 1 examination in the referenced article.

**Reference**

1. [How to match (or replace) a pattern except in situations s1, s2, s3...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23589174)
2. [How to match a pattern unless...](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html)